# How to switch PHP one version to another version in MAC OS?

Tags: php

I have installed php7.1 using homebrew in mac. But when i try php -version it shows 5.5. How can I switch version. I could not find my php instalation directory for php7.1 to set the path at bash_profile.

```
#brew install php71
Warning: homebrew/php/php71 7.1.7_19 is already installed

#php --version
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:21:45) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

**Edit**

I see my php installtion directory is under
 **/usr/local/etc/php/7.1** 
But it contains only php.ini and pear.conf files.

I tried

**export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php71)/bin:$PATH"**
But it didn't change my php version.( i tried php --version, still shows 5.5)

Comment: if you type in `which php`, what location does it give you ?

Comment: @giollianosulit /usr/bin/php

Comment: Here is the link: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/ they use a trusted PHP Packaged site and have an installation script. Use at your own risk I guess (I've been using it last 2-3 years no issues).

Comment: @giollianosulit only in that tab it shows the version as php 7.1, but in new tabs or console it shows older version. How can I edit php path in bash script?

Comment: @giollianosulit  edited like export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH it works. Before I put like export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/php5/bin didnt work. :(

Comment: Try this https://magestar.in/change-php-version-for-bash/

Comment: Have you tried just using `php71` instead of `php` in your cli?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this [guide](https://developerjack.com/blog/2016/installing-php71-with-homebrew/) helped me upgrade:

Make sure brew is up to date:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

(I kinda helped make that update happen! Woo!)

If you’re not already running php7 then you may need:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
```

And then the complicated part:

```
brew unlink php70 # or  brew unlink php55
brew install php71
```

And the result?

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.1.0 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2016 03:30:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Woohoo!

Comment: No this way didnt work. But like giolliiano said, that script worked. Only in that particular console tab it shows php version as 7.1, but in new consoles it is showing php 5.5 as version.

Comment: i edited like export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH . it works